# how send files via uart using kermit, minicom?

Tags: linux, uart, kermit

I use raspberry in my project, I want to send files via uart but I don't know how to implement kermit or minicom commands, in my script.
thank you

Comment: It's not clear that this is a programming question. Can you elaborate on what you need to accomplish?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think this is a question for [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) and not a programming question.